# Django Query without referencing fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

Quick overview:

I have a Forecast model setup which has a workflow_state.

Now I'm trying to query the Forecast for all the forecasts that are in a certain state AND the **current person logged in** is_staff.

If i was writing a raw query this wouldn't be an issue because i could write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM forecast WHERE forecast.workflow_state_id in (1,2,3,4) AND 1 = user.is_staff
```

However, when trying to write this in a queryset I can't figure out how to reference a constant.  I don't want to write a raw queryset and if possible want to avoid using the extra field.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's harder to reference a constant in an ORM query? It's a simple matter of passing it in.

Comment: I agree if you are refraining a field its very easy. However, in this case you are not.  You are more or less put a condition on the query without actually reference a field in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Your constant is only a `True`

```
Forecast.objects.filter(workflow_state__in=[1,2,3,4], user__is_staf=True)
```

Comment: user in this case is referring to the Forecast Model user not the user logged in.

Comment: Well, it's the same logic, if you show your models I could have a better idea about the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit makes things rather less than clear, but you seem to be asking how to do a check on the current logged-in user, rather than on the user referenced by the model. In which case, you don't do that in a query at all; your example SQL statement wouldn't work, and neither would doing it in the ORM. You do it in Python, of course:

```
if request.user.is_staff:
    forecasts = Forecast.objects.filter(workflow_state__in=[1,2,3,4])
```